# Non-binary Tree Height (Optimization)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

## Introduction

So I'm doing a course on edX and have been working on this practice assignment for
the better part of 3 hours, yet I still can't find a way to implement this method
without it taking to long and timing out the automatic grader.

I've tried 3 different methods all of which did the same thing.
Including 2 recursive approaches and 1 non-recursive approach (my latest).

The problem I think I'm having with my code is that the method to find children just takes way to long because it has to iterate over the entire list of nodes.

## Input and output format

Input includes N on the first line which is the size of the list which is given on line 2.

*Example:*

```
5
-1 0 4 0 3
```

**To build a tree from this**:
Each of the values in the array are a pointer to another index in the array such that in the example above 0 is a child node of -1 (index 0). Since -1 points to no other index it is the root node.

The tree in the example has the root node -1, which has two children 0 (index 1) and 0 (index 3). The 0 with index 1 has no children and the 0 with index 3 has 1 child: 3 (index 4) which in turn has only one child which is 4 (index 2).

The output resulting from the above input is 4. This is because the max height of the branch which included -1 (the root node), 0, 3, and 4 was of height 4 compared to the height of the other branch (-1, and 0) which was height 2.

If you need more elaborate explanation then I can give another example in the comments!

The output is the max height of the tree. The size of the input goes up to **100,000** which was where I was having trouble as it has to do that it in **exactly 3 seconds or under**.

## My code

Here's my latest non-recursive method which I think is the fastest I've made (still not fast enough). I used the starter from the website which I will also include beneath my code. Anyways, thanks for the help!

My code:

```
# python3

import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size

def height(node, parent_list):
        h = 0
        while not node == -1:
                h = h + 1
                node = parent_list[node]
        return h + 1

def search_bottom_nodes(parent_list):
        bottom_nodes = []
        for index, value in enumerate(parent_list):
                children = [i for i, x in enumerate(parent_list) if x == index]
                if len(children) == 0:
                        bottom_nodes.append(value)

        return bottom_nodes

class TreeHeight:
        def read(self):
                self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
                self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

        def compute_height(self):
                # Replace this code with a faster implementation
                bottom_nodes = search_bottom_nodes(self.parent)
                h = 0
                for index, value in enumerate(bottom_nodes):
                        h = max(height(value, self.parent), h)
                return h


def main():
  tree = TreeHeight()
  tree.read()
  print(tree.compute_height())

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

edX starter:

```
# python3

import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size

class TreeHeight:
        def read(self):
                self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
                self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

        def compute_height(self):
                # Replace this code with a faster implementation
                maxHeight = 0
                for vertex in range(self.n):
                        height = 0
                        i = vertex
                        while i != -1:
                                height += 1
                                i = self.parent[i]
                        maxHeight = max(maxHeight, height);
                return maxHeight;

def main():
  tree = TreeHeight()
  tree.read()
  print(tree.compute_height())

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: I can't really understand how you construct a tree from a list. Can you post detailed rules step-by-step?

Comment: Yeah an expected output would be helpful here, your explanation of how you're building the tree isn't great

Comment: Okay I added a better explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cache the previously computed heights of the nodes you've traversed through in a dict and reuse them when they are referenced as parents.

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size

class TreeHeight:
    def height(self, node):
        if node == -1:
            return 0
        if self.parent[node] in self.heights:
            self.heights[node] = self.heights[self.parent[node]] + 1
        else:
            self.heights[node] = self.height(self.parent[node]) + 1
        return self.heights[node]

    def read(self):
        self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
        self.heights = {}

    def compute_height(self):
        maxHeight = 0
        for vertex in range(self.n):
            maxHeight = max(maxHeight, self.height(vertex))
        return maxHeight;

def main():
    tree = TreeHeight()
    tree.read()
    print(tree.compute_height())

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Given the same input from your question, this (and your original code) outputs:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is one of the reasons I love programming. I've been trying for the last two days to solve this problem (decided not to give up), the course gave no explanation or anything so I had to figure out the format and everything myself. This solution kind of blew my mind because of how simple it was!! I still have a long way to go as a programmer.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I totally agree. The process of figuring out the best algorithm given a problem is why we love programming. :-)